# Why runs my SmartContract out of gas when I add a simple function

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle, openzeppelin

I have a simple token derived from openzeppelin's `MintableToken`.

However, when I either add a Constructor OR another function, I am constantly running out of gas. But when I add ONLY one of both, either the Constructor OR the function, everything works fine.

My question is: how can I add several functions together with a constructor into my SmartContract?

## The Token-Code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.22;

import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/MintableToken.sol";

contract HaioToken is MintableToken {
    string public name = "Haio Token";
    string public symbol = "HAI";
    uint8 public decimals = 18;

    uint256 public cap;

    constructor(uint256 _cap) public {
        cap = _cap;
    }

    function test(address _to) public returns (bool) {
        return true;    
    }

}
```

## Migrations:

2_deploy_contracts.js:

```
var HaioToken = artifacts.require("HaioToken");

module.exports = function(deployer, network, accounts) {
  const hardCap = 25000000;

  return deployer
      .then(() => {
          return deployer.deploy(HaioToken, hardCap);
      })
};
```

When I want to deploy the code, I get the following error message:

> Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas

If I remove either the constructor or the test-function, everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are running the migration with truffles default settings that came out of the box after running "`truffle init`" isn't it?

You should raise the gas you want to send on contract deployment this way in `truffle.js` (or `truffle-config.js` on Windows):

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*",
      gas: 5000000
    }
  }
};
```

(The value of 5000000 is an example that mostly works out of the box and if you don't have to care because developing on a local testnet :) )